# Android INJECT_EVENTS permission (Android 13)

Tags: android, android-studio, events, android-permissions, inject

**I am facing issue while i try to initiate a touch event**

java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting input events requires the caller (or the source of the instrumentation, if any) to have the INJECT_EVENTS permission.

```
public static void injectEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        Instrumentation m_Instrumentation = new Instrumentation();
        m_Instrumentation.sendPointerSync(e); // getting exception here
    }
```

tried to signed apk

Answer (score 0):

You need to add INJECT_EVENTS permission in your manifest file to sign your apk. Add the following permission to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS"/>
```

Then you have to sign your apk with the same signature that the system is signed with.

You have to run your app on `/system` so that it gains access to the permissions. To do so, run the following commands in the emulator terminal:

```
su
mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
cp /sdcard/APP.apk /system/app
```

If you want to use adb, then do the following:

```
adb remount
adb shell cp /sdcard/APP.apk /system/app
```

To do the above, you device needs to be rooted. [What is a rooted device?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rooting_(Android))

To root your device: [Rooting a device](https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-root-android-device)

Comment: already added this does not work.

Comment: Did you sign your apk with the system signature?

Comment: how that can be done?
Are you asking me to make a signed apk ?

Comment: System signatures are located in directory <root-of-android-source-tree>/build/target/product/security. You can use them to sign your application with system privileges.

Comment: Ok trying to find out how i will run this cmd

Comment: is there any possibility to do it without rooting device

Comment: According to Google, only system apps are granted the INJECT_EVENTS permission. Third party apps cannot use this permission. So, you have to make your app a system app, for that you will have to root your device.

Comment: Thanks Dinux 
Can you share google document that says this is not possible or any link ?
That could help me a little more

Comment: [Permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview) Read the Signature Permissions and Special Permissions part iin the link.