# A SecurityException occurred on my Android device

Tags: java, android, adb

Device: Xiaomi 12S (Android 13)

I connected my phone to my computer for USB debugging, and I'm trying to use cmd commands to simulate clicks on the phone:

```
adb shell input swipe 447 572 447 572 737
```

Then an error occurred:

```
Exception occurred while executing 'swipe':
java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting input events requires the caller (or the source of the instrumentation, if any) to have the INJECT_EVENTS permission.
```

And no click event occurred on my device.

I tried looking for similar questions in stackoverflow:

[Android INJECT_EVENTS permission (Android 13)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75830886/android-inject-events-permission-android-13)

But the solution to that problem doesn't work for me. Because I execute adb shell through cmd command.

My settings:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you're running the `adb shell <>` command from an application (likely a test app) and not from a terminal.

- Do you have the lockscreen on? Test with the screen on, and the lock screen disabled. If the (unprivileged?) test attempts to touch the lock-screen process (systemUI?), that could explain java.lang.SecurityException
- What app are you trying to simulate clicks for? And does your test application (the one executing the `adb shell <>`) have a manifest (with these permissions specified)? Are both APKs signed with the same key? (which's a requirement for you to be able to inject events from the test apk to the app-under-test)
- Since the shell implicitly gets INJECT_EVENTS permission, can you run this exact `adb shell <>` command successfully (you should be able to - if not file a bug under https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=192795&template=1310483).
  PS: Unlikely.. but if it's a system app, it should be signed by the platform key

Comment: No. I'm running that command from a terminal. That's Windows' cmd.